# getting "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources" when using rest API in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, rest-api, token

AUTH REST API:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pwd'];

    //$email='memotest@gmailtest.com';
    //$pass='memo@123';

$userData= array("username" => "api", "password" => "*********");
$link = "4ao8yk15rvchyqhc.mojostratus.io";


//generateApiToken();

$ch = curl_init("$link/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
$token = curl_exec($ch);



 $ch = curl_init("$link/index.php/rest/V1/Login/check/$email/$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_encode($token)));
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$result = json_decode($result, True);
echo "<pre>";

var_dump($result);die;
```

---

And Result :
[image]

Comment: Have you created new API with endpoint as rest/V1/Login/check/email/pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user `api` needs to have a role with permissions to access that resource.

As a debug method though, I would first try to `var_dump($token)` to make sure you are first getting the token.